# Dynamic Components in RAD Studio

Tags: java, c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a program in RAD Studio/C++ Builder. In Java, I was able to make a "Matrix of Textfields" in a JPanel. The size of this matrix depends on user.

For example, when the user selects 10, the Matrix of Texfields will be 11 TextFields by 10 Textfields in size, when the user selects 20, it will become 21 Textfields by 20 textfield. The Jpanel also increases its size according to the number of textfields.

But I decided to move to C++ because of performance issues. Is it possible to do that on RAD Studio, or in Visual Studio, or in QT? I dont want use Table. Thanks!(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

Ammm... Are you talking about gui textfields? Not familiar with JPanel.

In Qt you can use    [`QVboxLayOut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvboxlayout.html) (or other layout) and add as many widgets (QLabel, QLineEdit or whatever you need) as you want to.

Just start to create what you need and use google.